# Blender example

Tags: python

Where may I get an example of blender python script? Currently, I'm working on doing a whole python script from scratch to import, operate, export models. And I'm stuck in some issues.

Comment: Blender comes with plenty of scripts preinstalled. You can also go to the text editor and open any of the builtin sample templates from the menu

Comment: you can also just search for python in here...there are lot's of example + explanation ;)